# A way to backup data(databases, collections, documents) in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, backup, nosql

do you know any tool to backup data in mongodb? Like mysqldump in mongodb

thank you in advance!

Comment: Please consider a basic research before asking question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810935/mongodb-backup-plan/3811074#3811074) from "[MongoDB backup plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810935/mongodb-backup-plan)" question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look also into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495540/how-to-use-the-dumped-data-by-mongodump/5497138#comment-7201432) one my questions about how to do daily backups and restore data from backup.